# Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE - Actuator not available HTTP 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, tomcat9

Trying to use actuator in a Spring Boot web app. I don't know whether it matters but the web app is deployed as a WAR on a standalone Tomcat 9 server.

I got the following dependencies:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
```

In the application.yml file I have:

```
...
management:
  server:
    port: 8080
    address: localhost
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
...
```

The Tomcat log file (catalina.out) says:

```
...
2019-08-07 11:51:04.433  INFO 6913 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
...
```

However, when I go to http://localhost:8080/actuator I get 404. What do I miss here ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Since spring boot 2 the actuator falls under `actuator/<endpoint>` e.g. `actuator/health`

Comment: To be precise, the actuator falls under /actuator while the different endpoints, i.e. health, falls under /actuator/healh.

Answer (score 2):

Correct URL is http://host:port/war-name/actuator.

Sorry for bothering.